# Georeferenced PDF is checked but doesn't georeference

Tags: georeferencing, geospatial-pdf, avenza

I have checked the georeference option for my exported PDF but when I import it into Avenza PDF Maps it says it is not georeferenced.  I have had this work for other maps but a new map I opened will not work.  My new map has an aerial and a polygon I drew and that is all.

Comment: What software are you exporting from ?

Comment: My guess is that you're using ArcGIS, since there's an option in the pdf export that is a checkbox as you describe. However you should **edit** your question to clarify. I further suspect that if all you had was an aerial and a polygon you drew, it's possible the dataframe had no coordinate system set and neither the image or polygon shapefile/feature class have one either, and thus there is no georeferencing to export (or be read by Avenza).